# Replace \r\n with newline in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

How do I replace the string "\r\n" with the same characters?

Example:

```
Hello World.\r\nHello World.
```

replaced with:

```
Hello World.
Hello World.
```

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL-h</kbd> and the Replace dialog will open. Type `\\r\\n` in "Find what" and `\r\n` in "Replace with". Finally, select search mode **Extended (\r, \n, \t, \x..., \0)** and click "Replace All".

Comment: works in Programmer's notepad as well.  Select "Allow backslash expressions" and do the same

Comment: Does that work in newer versions of Notepad++? Or does it require selecting the option "Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x)"?

Comment: Search mode has to be "Extended" to work.

Comment: This also works in notepad2 in case anyone is interested. Check regular expression search when replacing

Comment: You could also do what I did and turn off extended search then replace \r\n with some unique string like "~~~~" then turn extended search back on and replace that string with \r\n. An extra step but it works.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I had to replace it with \r\n but it did work

Comment: Do not forget to move the text cursor to the beginning of the text before replacing. Otherwise, it won't work. This always gets me.

Comment: NB: this process can be automated using a Notepad++ macro. Just follow the Macro record and save process

Answer (score 16):

In the find screen, on the replace tab choose extended search.
In the find text box put `\\r\\n`, and in the replace text box put `\r\n`.

Comment: Does this actually work, or do you need to do escaping?

Comment: I had escaping, but I had to double escape it for it to show up right here (ie \\\\r\\\\n instead of \\r\\n).

Comment: So did you just now have to quadruple escape that in the comment? ^^^^^^^

Comment: No thankfully it doesn't try to interpret comments ...

Answer (score 3):

I tried the top voted answer, but I couldn't get it to work for my newer version of Notepad++. I had to reverse what they did. So:

Press `CTRL-h` and the Replace dialog will open. Type `\r\n` in "Find what" and `\\r\\n` in "Replace with". Then select search mode **Extended (\r, \n, \t, \x..., \0)** and click "Replace All".

Literally what Marcus did but reversed worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: your way will convert the real the new line to the literal `\r\n` in the file, whereas the question is about **converting the literal `\r\n` to new lines**

Comment: I had text just like OP in my notepad++, and it worked.
Where it would literally say something like: *Hello World.\r\nHello World.* to be: 
Hello

World
With my version of Notepad++, doing the top voted answer did not fix it for me, but switching it did work for me.
(I can't get stack overflow to register that I put a new line in between Hello and World... So just know that between Hello and World, it has a new line like how it should)

Answer (score 1):

Copy a newline and use the Search and Replace function to replace \r\n with the newline. The newline character will show up as an empty box.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work earlier.